# Does ABS() work with dates?

Tags: mysql, function, datetime

Am i correct in thinking that ABS() does not work with datetime in MySQL because it is a mathematical function?

I am trying to return the row with the date value nearest 1st July 2015.  Either side of this date, whichever one is closest, i would like to return.

I have done some research and it all leads me back to ABS(), but i cant get it to work and i am guessing this is because of the reason above...mathematical function.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ABS() on the results of some [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), such as DATEDIFF, or on the difference between two TO_SECONDS() calls.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried this:

    abs(timestampdiff(month, H1DAT, '2015-07-01'))

But it just returns a number of days of something...not sure what.

Comment: What `abs(timestampdiff(month, H1DAT, '2015-07-01'))` does is return the value of abs(07 - (whatever the numeric value of month is in `H1DAT`)) I dont think this is what you are looking for

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn that would return a number of _months_; from the docs _"The unit for the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument."_ Why jump to TIMESTAMPDIFF, when DATEDIFF appears to have the exact precision you need?

Comment: Thanks - to be honest i was just playing about with it.  I ended up using subqueries to pull the closes date <= and then another subquery to pull the closest date >=.  Not the most efficient but there are time limitations on this project so i am handing the data over as is tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. In the official [MySql Date and Time Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), There is no method for ABS() or even to estimate the closest date. You may have to work around this with a programming language you are comfortable and familiar with. I hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks - It helps in that i now know the answer....i think.  But it doesn't help me with my problem! :)  I wont mark anything as answer yet, will give it more time for people to view.

Comment: It also helps if you give more insight as to what your original project is about so we can help. Are you using this in a MySql stored procedure, is it a part of an estimator app, you know little things like that can go a long way :)